# Enhanced Spectrum Chloroplasts

Tags: genetics, plant-physiology, photosynthesis, chloroplasts, crispr

As far as I'm aware, chloroplasts produce energy through the use of photosynthesis which essentiall converts CO2 and Water into Glucose (I'm an engineer by trade so really wracking my brains to the last time I studied biology formally).

The pigment in chloroplasts, chlorophyll, makes the plant appear green due to the fact that it absorbs red and blue light, reflecting the green.

My question is this, would it be possible to extend the light spectrum absorbed by the chloroplasts, perhaps through the use of very careful genetic engineering and manipulation of the pigments contained within, in order to increase their energy absorbtion rate.

In essence, could you could make them absorb a wider range of frequencies for use with photosynthesis and thus enable much faster glucose/ATP synthesis?

If this were possible, how much of an evolutionary advantage would it provide?